# The page isn’t redirecting properly in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mysqli

I am trying to redirect to another page if a certain condition is met. I am new to Codeigniter, yet to understand the framework.

I have an external page which check the database for a condition, after which redirect to the page involved.

Challenge:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> ```
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
> ```

if I access

**http://localhost:83/law/**
in the browswer, instead of redirecting to either 
**http://localhost:83/law/b02.php**
or 
**http://localhost:83/law/index.php** 
it redirects to:

***http://localhost:83/law/admin/b02.php***

Don't know where the **admin dir** comes from

**sys_config.php**

```
<?php 
include ('application/config/functions.php');
require_once("application/config/cons.php");

    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
     $sql ="SELECT host FROM tray WHERE host = '$host'";

       $ret = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
       $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ret);


    if ($row['host'] != '' && $row['host'] == $host) {
        #$dir = base_url("index.php");
        redirect("index.php", true);
    } else {
        //echo "<p>Nothing matched your query.</p>";
        redirect("b02.php", true);

    }
 ?>
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteBase /law/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sys_config?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: read their documentation, it will help you to get start up. here's the link https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Comment: are you getting the user's action for it's corresponding redirection?

Comment: this doesn't look like codeigniter code.

Comment: @Alex, I added some external pages which is out of codeigniter scope.

Comment: well something is giving you an endless redirect loop